# try with resources introduce unreachable bytecode

Tags: java, exception, jvm, try-catch, javac

Is it possible that javac generates unreachable bytecode for the following procedure?

```
public void ex06(String name) throws Exception {
    File config = new File(name);
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(config);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    fos , "rw"))) {
        bar();
    }
}
```

When I look into the exception table of the bytecode (javap -v) there are the following entries that look strange:

```
43    48    86   Class java/lang/Throwable
43    48    95   any
```

and

```
21   135   170   Class java/lang/Throwable
21   135   179   any
```

Now the problem is that some code is only reachable if the exceptions of type "any" rather than Throwable are caught. Is there any situation where this can actually happen?

====== EDIT ======
Thanks for the answers so far. Let me give another piece of evidence to show that I really don't understand exception handling:
Consider the following procedure

```
Object constraintsLock;
private String[] constraints;
private String constraint;
public void fp01() {
    // Add this constraint to the set for our web application
    synchronized (constraintsLock) {
        String results[] =
            new String[constraints.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < constraints.length; i++)
            results[i] = constraints[i];            
        results[constraints.length] = constraint;
        constraints = results;
    }   
}
```

If you look in the bytecode you have:

```
    65: astore        4
    67: aload_1       
    68: monitorexit   
    69: aload         4
```

and the exception table

```
  Exception table:
     from    to  target type
         7    62    65   any
        65    69    65   any
```

Does that mean that this guy can loop forever?

Comment: Please post the full bytecode.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26793257/example.txt

Comment: and here is the jimple code (which is generated by soot):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26793257/example.jimple.txt
I put two comments in there to point out the relevant lines.

Comment: Seems to be related (if not duplicate) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386917/strange-exception-table-entry-produced-by-suns-javac

Comment: Just for the record: this got finally fixed in Java 11 ea+7. Reference: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8194978

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**TL;DR**: this has been addressed with JDK-11; at the end of the answer is an example of JDK-11’s `javac` output for comparison.

The fact that every throwable is an instance of `java.lang.Throwable` is implied at various places of the Java byte code/ JVM. Even if handlers for *any* were meant to represent something possibly outside the `Throwable` type hierarchy, that idea fails as today’s class files must have a `StackMapTable` for methods containing exception handlers and that `StackMapTable` will refer to the *any* throwable as an instance of `java.lang.Throwable`[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.athrow).

Even with the old type inferring verifier, a handler which re-throws a throwable implicitly contains the assertion that *any* throwable is an instance of `java.lang.Throwable` as that’s the only object `athrow` is allowed to throw.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.athrow

> The *objectref* must be of type `reference` and must refer to an object that is an instance of class `Throwable` or of a subclass of `Throwable`.

*Short answer: no, it is impossible to have a situation where something other than an instance of `java.lang.Throwable` (or a subclass) can be thrown or caught*.

I tried to create a minimal example of a try-with-resource statement to analyse the output of `javac`. The result clearly shows that the structure is an artifact of how `javac` works internally but can’t be intentional.

The example looks like this:

```
public static void tryWithAuto() throws Exception {
    try (AutoCloseable c=dummy()) {
        bar();
    }
}
private static AutoCloseable dummy() {
    return null;
}
private static void bar() {
}
```

(I compiled with `jdk1.8.0_20`)

I put the exception handler table at the beginning of the resulting byte code so it’s easier to refer to the location while looking at the instruction sequence:

```
Exception table:
   from    to  target type
     17    23    26   Class java/lang/Throwable
      6     9    44   Class java/lang/Throwable
      6     9    49   any
     58    64    67   Class java/lang/Throwable
     44    50    49   any
```

Now to the instructions:

The beginning is straightforward, two local variables are used, one to hold the `AutoCloseable` (index 0), the other for the possible throwable (index 1, initialized with `null`). `dummy()` and `bar()` are invoked, then the `AutoCloseable` is checked for `null` to see whether it must be closed.

```
     0: invokestatic  #2         // Method dummy:()Ljava/lang/AutoCloseable;
     3: astore_0
     4: aconst_null
     5: astore_1
     6: invokestatic  #3         // Method bar:()V
     9: aload_0
    10: ifnull        86
```

We get here if the `AutoCloseable` is not `null` and the first weird thing happens, the throwable which is definitely `null` is checked for `null`

```
    13: aload_1
    14: ifnull        35
```

The following code will close the `AutoCloseable`, guarded by the first exception handler from the table above which will invoke `addSuppressed`. Since at this point, variable #1 is `null` this is dead-code:

```
    17: aload_0
    18: invokeinterface #4,  1   // InterfaceMethod java/lang/AutoCloseable.close:()V
    23: goto          86
    26: astore_2
    27: aload_1
    28: aload_2
    29: invokevirtual #6         // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    32: goto          86
```

Note that the last instruction of the dead code is `goto 86`, a branch to a `return` so if the code above was not dead code anyway, we could start wondering why bother invoking `addSuppressed` on a `Throwable` that is ignored right afterwards.

Now follows the code that is executed if variable #1 is `null` (read, always). It simply invokes `close` and branches to the `return` instruction, not catching any exception, so an exception thrown by `close()` propagates to the caller:

```
    35: aload_0
    36: invokeinterface #4,  1   // InterfaceMethod java/lang/AutoCloseable.close:()V
    41: goto          86
```

Now we enter the second exception handler, covering the body of the `try` statement, declared to catch `Throwable`, read all exceptions. It stores the `Throwable` into the variable #1, as expected, but also stores it into the obsolete variable #2. Then it re-throws the `Throwable`.

```
    44: astore_2
    45: aload_2
    46: astore_1
    47: aload_2
    48: athrow
```

The following code is the target of *two* exception handlers. First, its the target of the superfluous *any* exception handler that covers the same range as the `Throwable` handler, hence, as you suspected, this handler doesn’t do anything. Further, it is the target of the fourth exception handler, catching anything and covering the exception handler above so we catch the re-thrown exception of instruction #48 right one instruction later. To make things even more funny, the exception handler covers more than the handler above; ending at #50, exclusive, it even covers the first instruction of itself:

```
    49: astore_3
```

So the first thing is to introduce a third variable to hold the same throwable. Now the the `AutoCloseable` is checked for `null`.

```
    50: aload_0
    51: ifnull        84
```

Now the throwable of variable #1 is checked for `null`. It can be `null` only if the hypothetical throwable not being a `Throwable` exists. But note that the entire code would be rejected by the verifier in that case as the `StackMapTable` declares all variables and operand stack entries holding the *any throwable* to be assignment compatible to `java.lang.Throwable`

```
    54: aload_1
    55: ifnull        78
    58: aload_0
    59: invokeinterface #4,  1   // InterfaceMethod java/lang/AutoCloseable.close:()V
    64: goto          84
```

Last but not least we have the exception handler which handles exception thrown by close when a pending exception exists which will invoke `addSuppressed` and re-throws the primary exception. It introduces another local variables which indicates that `javac` [indeed never uses `swap`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9722421/2711488) even where appropriate.

```
    67: astore        4
    69: aload_1
    70: aload         4
    72: invokevirtual #6         // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    75: goto          84
```

So the following two instructions are only invoked if *catch any* could imply something other than `java.lang.Throwable` which is not the case. The code path joins at #84 with the regular case.

```
    78: aload_0
    79: invokeinterface #4,  1   // InterfaceMethod java/lang/AutoCloseable.close:()V
    84: aload_3
    85: athrow

    86: return
```

So the bottom line is that the additional exception handler for *any* is responsible for dead code of four instructions only, #54, #55, #78 and #79 while there is even more dead code for other reasons (#17 - #32), plus a strange “throw-and-catch” (#44 - #48) code which might also be an artifact of the idea to handle *any* differently than `Throwable`. Further, one exception handler has a wrong range covering itself which might be related to “[Strange exception table entry produced by Sun's javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386917/strange-exception-table-entry-produced-by-suns-javac)” as [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615417/try-with-resources-introduce-unreachable-bytecode#comment40121527_25615417).

---

As a side-note, Eclipse produces more straightforward code taking only 60 bytes rather than 87 for the instruction sequence, having the two expected exception handlers only and three local variables instead of five. And within that more compact code it handles the possible case that the exception thrown by the body might be the same as the one throw by `close` in which case `addSuppressed` must not be called. The `javac` generated code does not care for this.

```
     0: aconst_null
     1: astore_0
     2: aconst_null
     3: astore_1
     4: invokestatic  #18        // Method dummy:()Ljava/lang/AutoCloseable;
     7: astore_2
     8: invokestatic  #22        // Method bar:()V
    11: aload_2
    12: ifnull        59
    15: aload_2
    16: invokeinterface #25,  1  // InterfaceMethod java/lang/AutoCloseable.close:()V
    21: goto          59
    24: astore_0
    25: aload_2
    26: ifnull        35
    29: aload_2
    30: invokeinterface #25,  1  // InterfaceMethod java/lang/AutoCloseable.close:()V
    35: aload_0
    36: athrow
    37: astore_1
    38: aload_0
    39: ifnonnull     47
    42: aload_1
    43: astore_0
    44: goto          57
    47: aload_0
    48: aload_1
    49: if_acmpeq     57
    52: aload_0
    53: aload_1
    54: invokevirtual #30        // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    57: aload_0
    58: athrow
    59: return
```

```
  Exception table:
     from    to  target type
         8    11    24   any
         4    37    37   any
```

Starting with JDK-11, `javac` compiles the example to

```
Code:
   0: invokestatic  #2        // Method dummy:()Ljava/lang/AutoCloseable;
   3: astore_0
   4: invokestatic  #3        // Method bar:()V
   7: aload_0
   8: ifnull        42
  11: aload_0
  12: invokeinterface #4,  1  // InterfaceMethod java/lang/AutoCloseable.close:()V
  17: goto          42
  20: astore_1
  21: aload_0
  22: ifnull        40
  25: aload_0
  26: invokeinterface #4,  1  // InterfaceMethod java/lang/AutoCloseable.close:()V
  31: goto          40
  34: astore_2
  35: aload_1
  36: aload_2
  37: invokevirtual #6        // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
  40: aload_1
  41: athrow
  42: return
```

```
Exception table:
   from    to  target type
       4     7    20   Class java/lang/Throwable
      25    31    34   Class java/lang/Throwable
```

It now has even less redundancy than the ECJ compiled version. It still doesn’t check whether the throwables are the same, but I’d rather add another exception handler entry covering the `addSuppressed` invocation instruction and targeting the re-throwing code at `40`, rather than inserting a pre-check for this corner case. Then, it would still be less code than the alternatives.

Comment: Great analysis. I came to more or less the same conclusions while trying to answer this last week. It seems likely that it's a ~bug~. In any case, +1 and all. Thanks!

Comment: This explains why Emma code coverage in eclipse is significantly higher than maven/Sonar coverage when you have a lot of try-with-resources blocks.