# Try with multiple resource causes a sonar qube issue

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

Please see the code snippet

```
try (InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("hello.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
```

But `sonarQube` complaints below error in the above line

> Correctness - Nullcheck of value previously dereferenced(line starting with BufferedReader ) .

Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: I don't think this is the correct line. The error means that you are doing a null check but already accessed the variable. Can you show more code?

Comment: Are you checking for the nullness of `inputStream` anywhere within the try body?

Comment: I guess, that’s because the code analyzer uses the compiled code and in case of try-with-resource, [it’s a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25746587/2711488), having unreachable code and redundant checks. But if that’s the cause for your problem, the good news is that you get rid of it when updating to JDK 11, even when compiling for `--release 8`.

Comment: By the way, you should use `this.getClass() .getResourceAsStream("/hello.txt")` instead of going through the class loader. This way, the access is compatible with modular software, as a class loader may have multiple modules, but you’re usually referring to the resource with the class’ module. Actually, if you’re not intending to allow resolving to different resources when executed for a subclass, you should use `ActualClassName.class .getResourceAsStream("/hello.txt")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hello.txt")` can return `null` and you're using it just after to create the `BufferedReader`, without checking for null value.

Comment: So it means, I can't use try with resource in this case rite?

Comment: Consider using the method [Files.newBufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-)

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel The method in `Files` is good for files, not for resources.

Comment: Indeed, so you can just move the `getResourceAsStream` above the `try` and check for null value